# Smoooth looping of audio track in my react native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, expo

I'm building an audio player as a mobile app using React Native and aiming to achieve perfect transition i.e audio to next audio without any silence, when looping. There's a heart beat, half second skip in between each song and when looping any given song that there's no sound.

Currently using Expo Audio player:
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/
Also tried:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vlc-media-player

My Audioprovider.js where the logic is located looks like this:

```
 onPlaybackStatusUpdate = async playbackStatus => {
    if (playbackStatus.isLoaded && playbackStatus.isPlaying) {
      this.updateState(this, {
        playbackPosition: playbackStatus.positionMillis,
        playbackDuration: playbackStatus.durationMillis,
      });
    }
    if (playbackStatus.isLoaded && !playbackStatus.isPlaying) {
      storeAudioForNextOpening(
        this.state.currentAudio,
        this.state.currentAudioIndex,
        playbackStatus.positionMillis
      );
    }
    let durationSeconds = playbackStatus.durationMillis/1000;
    let positionSeconds = playbackStatus.positionMillis/1000;

    if (playbackStatus.didJustFinish ||  (parseInt(durationSeconds)-2 === parseInt(positionSeconds))) {
      if (this.state.isPlayListRunning) {
        let audio;

        const indexOnPlayList = this.state.activePlayList.audios.findIndex(
          ({ id }) => id === this.state.currentAudio.id
        );
        const nextIndex = this.state.isLoop ? indexOnPlayList : indexOnPlayList + 1;
        audio = this.state.activePlayList.audios[nextIndex];
        if (!audio) audio = this.state.activePlayList.audios[0];
        const indexOnAllList = this.state.audioFiles.findIndex(
          ({ id }) => id === audio.id
        );
        const status = await playNext(this.state.playbackObj, audio.url);
        return this.updateState(this, {
          soundObj: status,
          isPlaying: true,
          currentAudio: audio,
          currentAudioIndex: indexOnAllList,
        });
      }
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible?

Github:
https://github.com/samirhassen/OctaCoil